# copies of Visual Basic 3 and 4

Tags: ide

I need to get ahold of copies of Visual Basic 3 and 4.  I tried eBay.  Any other ideas?

Comment: The FAQ allows questions that are related to "software tools commonly used by programmers". Before I vote to reopen, can anyone convince me _why_ this question isn't covered by that clause? I suppose "commonly" may preclude VB3/4 but there are BCPL questions and I'm pretty certain that's a rarer beast than old editions of VB.

Comment: @paxdiablo: I interpreted that point of the FAQ to mean that questions covering *how to use* software tools for the purpose of programming were on-topic. *Where to buy/download them* seems like a bit of a stretch. But that's just my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

Both are available through an MSDN subscription.

Comment: Which level?  And, not that I doubt you, but is there anything online that states this?

Comment: i can confirm this:  Available to Levels: VS Pro with MSDN Pro (VL); VS Pro with MSDN Premium (Empower); Developer AA; VS Pro with MSDN (Retail); MSDN Enterprise; MSDN Universal (Retail); VSTS Team Suite (VL);

Comment: VSTS Architecture (VL); VS Premium with MSDN (MPN); VSTS Test (VL); VS Pro with MSDN Premium (MPN); MSDN Universal (VL); VSTS Database (VL); VS Pro with MSDN Premium (Retail); VSTS Test (Retail); VSTS Development (Retail); VSTS Architecture (Retail); VSTS Team Suite (Retail); VSTS Database (Retail); BizSpark Admin; BizSpark; VS Pro with MSDN Embedded (Retail); VS Pro with MSDN Embedded (VL); VS Ultimate with MSDN (VL); VS Premium with MSDN (VL); VS Pro with MSDN (VL); VS Premium with MSDN (Retail); VS Ultimate with MSDN (Retail); VS Ultimate with MSDN (MPN);

Comment: What would be the cheapest option?

Answer (score 2):

maybe this, not sure how legal.

http://www.emsps.com/oldtools/msvb.htm#vb3

Comment: "No licenses for any specific use of any software on media is being sold. Sales are ONLY made to computer professionals who understand the complexities of Microsoft software licensing." - that limits it a bit :-) And, if you're going to go rogue, you may as well find a torrent and save yourself a few pounds. Not that I'm suggesting that, of course.

Comment: Hmmm.... why can't they sell the license?  Is it really that complex?

Comment: @Joel: Have you ever actually _read_ an EULA? :-) See this for example (MsWord): Software Transfer. Except as specified in this Section, the initial licensee of the Software Product may make a one-time permanent transfer of this EULA and Software Product only directly to an end user. ... The transferee of such one-time transfer must agree to comply with the terms of this EULA, including the obligation not to further transfer this EULA and Software Product.

Comment: That last bit "EULA **and** Software Product" could make what these guys are doing legal if _both_ those items weren't transferred (though even that is arguable) but then you're buying software without the right to use it.